# Need help with basic factoring equation

Tags: factoring, quadratics

I'm just trying to brush up on my factoring of quadratic equations.

$$\frac1{x+3} + \frac1{x^2 + 5x +6}$$

$$\frac1{x+3} + \frac1{(x+2)(x+3)}$$

$$\frac{(x+2)(x+3) + (x+3)}{(x+2)(x+2)(x+3)}$$

Then I'm stuck. I think you can factor out the $(x+2)(x+3)$ from top and bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between your second and third step it can be improved: since you have 
$
\frac1{x+3} + \frac1{(x+2)(x+3)}
$
in the second step, you want to give all fractions a common denominator - the *least common denominator*. Since both terms have a $x+3$ in the denom. already, multiply the first term by $\frac{x+2}{x+2}$, and add the fractions to get 
$$
\frac{x+2}{(x+2)(x+3)} + \frac 1{(x+2)(x+3)} = \frac{x+3}{(x+2)(x+3)} = \frac{1}{x+2}.
$$

Comment: It is not an error, simple redundancy.

Comment: @Kaster though I am unsure how line 3 was arrived at, it is correct that it is indeed merely redundancy, and perhaps I should soften my language. However, I meant to indicate more that there was a more simple/efficient way of thinking of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The top can be rewritten as ((x+2)+1)(x+3) = (x+3)^2. The bottom should be (x+2)(x+3)(x+3), if you go with the "redundant" approach. Two (x+3)'s, not two (x+2)'s. Then you can factor (x+3)^2 from top and bottom and are left with 1/(x+2), as others have noted.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
&{1\over{x+3}}+{1\over{x^2+5x+6}}\to\\  
&{1\over{x+3}}+{1\over{(x+2)(x+3)}}\to\\
&{x+2+1\over{(x+2)(x+3)}}\to\\ 
&{x+3\over{(x+2)(x+3)}}\to\\
&1\over{x+2}
\end{align}$$